# MYSQL workbench connection not starting

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have windows 8.1 and I am trying to install MYSQL workbench 5.2CE.
But it is showing this error :"Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)".In program files under mysql there is no bin folder and even in services.msc there is no process for mysql.
What should I do.
Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have a mysql service running?

Comment: I don't know ..in services there is no service for mysql

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench is only a client program and needs a server to work against. If you want to work with MySQL locally on Windows I recommend to use the MySQL Installer for Windows, which not only installes MySQL Workbench, but also a server of your choice (by default: the current GA version).

Once that is installed MySQL Workbench will automatically detect the server and you can immediately start a connection to it.